# Convert .keystore file to .jks file to sign IONIC V3 App

Tags: android, ionic-framework, keystore, android-keystore, jks

I built an App with IONIC 4 and uploaded to google play store. Unfortunately, as the IONIC 4 is using Cordova 8 engine the app is able to run on Android versions higher or equal to 7.

To cater for old Android users I rebuilt the app with IONIC 3 and it is working with older Android versions too.

The older version of the App which I built was signed with a .keystore file carrying keys. But the new version of the App (built with IONIC 3) requires a .jks file to sign the App.

Google demands that both versions be signed with the same keys. I am now stuck with importing the keys in the .keystore file to .jks file so that both versions be signed with same keys. Need your help on this.

Comment: Have you tried this already? The two files are the same thing.

Comment: Yes tried but it says "invalid format"

Comment: Wow. I could try finding out more about this for you. Can't guarantee today tho

Comment: ionic 3 and ionic 4 build process are the same and it both case it should work with same keystore
invalid format means you have invalid keystore or invalid credentials of that keystore

Comment: well. as I have explained clearly each version is looking for a different extension